# $R \setminus (S \cup T)$ . Where is $x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am sorry for the messy math symbols.

If I have the set:  $R \setminus(S \cup T)$  , is it correct to assume that:

$$R \setminus(S \cup T) = \{x: x∈ \mathbb{R} \text{ and } ( x \notin S \text{ and } x \notin T) \}$$

I am confused because if I had the set $S \cup T$ I would assume that:

$$(S \cup T)= \{x: x \in S \text{ or } x \in T\}$$

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is the relative complement. It's the set of $x$ that are in $R$ but not in $S\cup T$. If $x$ is _not_ in $S\cup T$, then it cannot be in $S$ and it cannot be in $T$; if it was in either $S$ or $T$, it would be in their union. Hence the _and_ in the above statement.

Comment: Parentheses, "$x \in R$ **and** not ($x \in S$ or $x \in T$)".

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It might be more enlightening if you rewrite the first one as

$$R\setminus (S\cup T) = \{x\in R \mbox{ and not } (x\in S \mbox{ or } x\in T)\}$$

Now you're using de Morgan's law, which is a rule from logic that says

not(X or Y) = not X and not Y

(it should be easy to convince yourself that this is true).

Comment: DeMorrgan's Law is a good way to think about this.

Comment: The minute you said Demorgan's law it got clear to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right. If $x$ is not in $(S$ or $T)$, then $x$ is not in $S$ and not in $T$. This sort of "flip" from or to and is referred to as [DeMorgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

$R \backslash (S \cup T)$ is the set of all $x \in R$, $x \notin (S \cup T)$. We can write that as $R \backslash (S \cup T) =  \{x \in R | \text{x not in S and x not in T}\}$. What you wrote is correct.

Think about it: $x \in S \cup T$ if $x \in S$ or $x \in T$. But the only way for $x$ not to be in $S \cup T$ is if it is not in $S$ **and** not in $T$. Otherwise, we could suppose that $x \in S$, and $x \notin T$. Then $x \in S \cup T$. So we must have $x \notin S$ and $x \notin T$.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is correct.
I think where you're getting confused is when you have to use [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demorgan%27s_Laws).
This can be converted logically as follows:
$$
x \in R \setminus (S \cup T) \to x \in R \wedge \neg (x \in S \vee x \in T)\\
x \in R \wedge (\neg x \in S \wedge \neg x \in T) \\
x \in R \wedge x \notin S \wedge x \notin T
$$
De Morgan's Law is applied in the last step and it converts the **or** to an **and**.